# rails formatting a custom json output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do would I format my model so that it will output a json document with an id and name field?

Because my model has custom field names and I am using tokeninput and it requires me to output it to id and name.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have so many options here, you can use jbuilder, rabl. But I think the easiest one is to use Active Model Serializers.

Let's say you have a model name **User**.

First install the bundle, then:

```
rails g serializer user
```

Then at app/serializers/user_serializer.rb:

```
class ArticleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name 
end
```

Comment: Although you can just do something like: *@users = User.all.to_json :only => [:id, :name]*;  *render :json => @users* in the controller but still I prefer Active Serializer since it organise the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to pass a only option to `to_json`

```
:only => [:id, :name]
```

For example, if you want to get id and name of `User`

```
User.all.to_json :only => [:id, :name]
```

If the model does not contain Id and Name as described by OP. Then you use custom select at the time of querying the db.

```
User.select('filed1 as id, field2 as name').all.to_json
```

Comment: I get this part, but my model does not have id or name. It has different field names, how do I pass modification so it will get outputted as id and name?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your controller

```rb
require 'json'

# ...

def show_json
  user_obj_to_json = User.first.to_json
  render user_obj_to_json
end
```

Comment: actually, what i am trying to do is change the field names of my current field names in my model. i have now category_id and category_name, i simply want them both changed to id and name.